# How to connect DELL computer to Samsung Frame Tv (2021)

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps

My TV arrived today and I was so excited to use it also as a second screen with my laptops (Dell XPS 13 & Dell Alienware R3 15"). My problem is that I cannot do that right now.

The wireless display setup seems extremely straightforward for most, except for dell users as I've seen in numerous posts such as [this one](https://www.dell.com/community/Networking-Internet-Bluetooth/Screen-mirroring-to-Samsung-Smart-TV/td-p/4710314).

I have admin accesses on my Alienware and every driver is up-to-date, but I observe a strange phenomenon. The TV can be "detected" but it cannot "connect" to my pc. I renamed the TV "Fancy Big Boi - 55", and it can be detected as "Autres appareils" which translates to "Other devices", but not as a **Projector**, which enables screen sharing/mirroring. And as you can see here, there is only one button : "Supprimer" which translates to "Delete".
[image]

And of course, I cannot find it when trying to connect to it as per the user guide.
[image]

Comment: The last entry in your link shows how to cast your screen to the TV. Have you tried all 3 methods?

Comment: For the first method, I don't have "Screen mirroring option" but a "PC to TV" option in source.... And there is no "waiting for a device to be connected" load screen.

For the second method, it concerns samsung smart phones & tablets so it doesn't apply to me.

I can't see the third method.